# Minecraft won’t leave full screen in Windows 10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10, monitor, minecraft-launcher

When we click on Minecraft launcher in menu bar it goes immediately to full screen and mouse has no cursor on the screen so the only option is via keyboard ‘ctrl alt delete’ sign out of computer. We can’t play it at all. There is no problem with gaming mouse or HP Envy new laptop otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried `F11` to unfullscreen it (`Fn` + `F11` on some keyboards)?